# Correct way to spawn a node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, spawn, babel-node

What is the correct way to spawn the following script from `package.json`:

```
"start": "nodemon --exec \"cd ./src && babel-node --only \".,../../../node_modules/@workspace/graphql/src\" server.js \"",
```

This is my try so far:

**start.js:**

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const args = [
  '--exec',
  '--only /".,../../../node_modules/@workspace/graphql/src/"',
  'server.js'
];

const opts = { stdio: 'inherit', cwd: 'src', shell: true };
let child = spawn('babel-node', args, opts);
```

I´m not getting the correct parameters on babel-node, as it is not compiling as the script does.

Another try with no success:

**start.js:**

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const args = [
  '--exec',
  '--only',
  '.,../../../node_modules/@workspace/graphql/src',
  'server.js'
];

const opts = { stdio: 'inherit', cwd: 'src', shell: true };
let child = spawn('babel-node', args, opts);
```

Also, no success.

How to correctly `spawn` the given script?

PS: I´ve changed `package.json` to:

```
"start": "node scripts/start.js",
```

Comment: Looks to me like you have a mistake in your path? `.,../`? Or is that deliberate in terms of 2 different paths? Also what parameters *aren't* being set properly? None? Some?

Comment: 2 different paths in a string. Look at the original script.

Comment: ok, do you have `babel-node` installed globally?

Comment: No, on the Lerna workspace....

Comment: Not familiar with Lerna - however, that's the one thing that sort of stands out for me, there is no path to the executable so unless it's in your global path just `babel-node` isn't going to work. It'll need to be `<path-to-exe>/babel-node`.

Comment: Really a problema with `babel-node` paths. Thanks.